# How to use the EntityFramework System.Data.Objects.ObjectView collection class?

Tags: entity-framework-5, msdn

When handling the `Selected` event of a `EntityDataSource`, the `Results` property of the `EntityDataSourceSelectedEventArgs` returns an `ObjectView` collection of my entities. I'm not sure what this class is. [This link to the Namepace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.aspx) doesn't mention the class.

Is there any documentation on this `System.Data.Objects.ObjectView` collection class? How would I convert an `ObjectView<T>` to a `List<T>`? Perhaps it's as simple as enumerating the collection and adding the items to a new `List<T>`, but some information about the class would be useful.

Comment: No, model-first. Basically I'm reusing the data from a EntityDataSource control so I don't have to run the query again. I managed to get the `e.Results.GetEnumerator()` working to extract items so far, but still not sure why it's undocumented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ObjectView class is internal and therefore you cannot find it on MSDN. The important bit of information is that it implements [IBindingListInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Cheers. Seems strange that we are given an internal collection class when handling the event args.

Comment: This is just an implementation of the interface. It is not that uncommon to return internal types (but still not very common as well - most of the times it is a public type).